# ValueError: probabilities are not non-negative

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I was using this code, when I did testing I was getting the above error

```
prob=self.maxBirthProb*(1-popDensity)
    maxBirthProb=self.maxBirthProb
    clearProb=self.clearProb
    if np.random.choice([True,False],p=[prob,1-prob]):
        return SimpleVirus(maxBirthProb,clearProb)
    raise NoChildException
```

Could Someone explain what that error means as it doesn't make sense that the probabilities are non-negative??

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: Its the question itself. ValueError: Probablilties are not non negative

Comment: Effectively, this means that your code is checking for probabilites which are only defined within `[0; 1]`. Opposed to that, it seems to produce negative values. But without a minimal working example, debugging is difficult.